# Excel: Perform a SUMIF where the criteria is a comma-delimited list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my first Excel worksheet, I have a table of IDs and Values:

```
ID  VALUE
1   30
2   35
3   14
4   92
```

In my second worksheet, I will provide a comma-delimited list of IDs in one column, and in the second column, I'd like the calculated sum of those IDs' values, like this:

```
IDs     SUM
1,2     65
2,3,4   141
3       14
```

How would I write the formula for the SUM column of the second worksheet? I'd like to avoid VBA if possible.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that, for the example tables you give:

1) Your source table is in the range `Sheet1!A1:B5` (with headers in row 1)

2) Your results table is in the range `Sheet2!A1:B4` (with headers in row 1)

3) The delimiter for the entries in column A of the results table is only ever a single comma

then, in `Sheet2!B2`, **array formula****:

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&Sheet1!A$2:A$5&",",","&A2&",")),Sheet1!B$2:B$5))`

Copy down to `B4`.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Excel may format two numbers like 1 and 234 delimited by a single comma, "1,234" as a thousands separator, one number. If you want it work with a comma delimited list of any number of spaces before/after the comma, removing all the spaces before using FIND() works

=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&Sheet1!A$2:A$5&",",","&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ", "")&",")),Sheet1!B$2:B$5))

Answer (score 1):

Consider delimiting the criteria with columns instead of commas, then you can simply add up a few Sumif formulas. Comma delimiting the criteria is a bad idea.

[image]

**EDIT:** Actually, why NOT use dozens of columns? Excel has plenty of them, so let's use them. Put the comma delimited list into a column. Maybe even on a different sheet. Use Text to Columns to separate the values into individual columns. Allow for a hundred. Then add a hundred columns with a single sumif formula for each column. At the very right, use a sum formula to total all sumif statements.

You can use VBA to do the Text to Columns thing and hide the columns with the split out values and the columns with the formulas, which leaves you with a column for your comma separated values next to a column with their respective totals.

Comment: That would be my preference as well, but this is a very simplified example. In reality the comma-delimited list could contain dozens of IDs.  It wouldn't be impossible to assign one per cell, but there would be dozens of columns instead of 1.

Comment: in that case you probably won't be able to avoid VBA

Comment: Actually, why not use dozens of columns. Put the comma delimited list into the first column. Use Text to c

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer

Answer (score 0):

you may use User defined function to achieve this.

```
Function GetSum(r As String) As Long
    Dim str1, str2
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim d As Long
    str1 = Split(r, ",")
    str2 = UBound(str1)
    For i = 0 To str2
        d = d + WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws1.Range("A:A"), str1(i), ws1.Range("B:B"))
    Next i
    GetSum = d
End Function
```

Assuming your data in both sheet1 and sheet 2 starts with A2 then
in Worksheet2 B2 apply the below formula

```
=getsum(A2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could always hide the colums from teylyns aswer and concatenate those hidden columns in a seperate column.

OR use a formula in the hidden colums like: left(right($G2,len($G2)-2),1). The minus 2 in the right() formula should go from 0 to 2 to 4 etc as you proceed to the next column. In the G column the user could specify the IDs like "1,2,3". You will also need an if function if the len()-something is negative to use the 0 value. Maybe also a function to replace " " by "".

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, right? Let me add my two cents.

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A$2:A$5,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(D2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),B$2:B$5))
```

Drag down.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&A$2:A$5&",",","&D3&","))*$B$2:$B$5)
```

without <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>