# Sum values in one column based on multiple conditions in one cell

Tags: excel

So my sheet looks like this:

[image]

I need to sum the values based on text in the products column.

Can someone explain to me how this is done without using VBA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: Perform a SUMIF where the criteria is a comma-delimited list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779282/excel-perform-a-sumif-where-the-criteria-is-a-comma-delimited-list)

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following formula in `Cell B2`

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(","& E$1:E$5&",",","&A2&",")),F$1:F$5))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

Got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38782821/6075259).

Comment: Worked out beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterHansen - If this solved your problem kindly accept it as answer by clicking tick mark at top left of answer.