# Sum values using lookup table, where lookup values are a list of values with comma delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to sum values based that equal a lookup value. However, that value is actually a list of values delimited by a comma. Below is an example of what I mean.

Suppose I have raw data in the form of `sheet1` below:

Sheet1:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID | VALUE |
| 2 | A | 30 |
| 3 | A | 50 |
| 4 | A | 20 |
| 5 | B | 10 |
| 6 | B | 20 |
| 7 | C | 70 |
| 8 | C | 40 |
| 9 | D | 30 |
| 10 | E | 50 |
| 11 | F | 20 |
| 12 | F | 30 |
| 13 | G | 10 |

And I have a look table that groups all IDs by their respective teams, as per `sheet2` below.

Sheet2:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEAM | IDS |
| 2 | Red | A, B |
| 3 | Blue | C, D |
| 4 | Green | E, F, G |

And I want to create a report where the user can select the team name, and the sum of the values in sheet1 will aggregate based on the selection, as per the following example. So the user would select "Green" in cell `B1` and it would return the sum of values that correspond to E, F, and G in `sheet1`.

Report:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Select Team: | Green |
| 2 | Sum: | 110 |

I have searched all over for a solution to this and was able to find something similar. I tried to repurpose the formula for my data but couldn't get it to work because I think that solution dealt with numbers rather than text.

[Excel: Perform a SUMIF where the criteria is a comma-delimited list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779282/excel-perform-a-sumif-where-the-criteria-is-a-comma-delimited-list/38782821)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Just want to add that I realize I could first parse out the IDs in `sheet2`, however I'm looking for a formula that can bypass that as my real dataset is quite large and parsing out the IDs under each team would explode the number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variation of @JvdV solution on the linked question:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!F1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

[image]

Note, this only works with Excel 2013 or later and only on PC.  FILTERXML is not available on Mac or prior to 2013.

---

If Mac or prior to 2013:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(F1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZY1:INDEX($ZY:$ZY,LEN(VLOOKUP(F1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(F1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution Scott. Is it possible to use this formula if there were more than 1 values columns. So in sheet1 let's say there's values in column B and C. Could I expand the sum range to account for C in your formula? I tried but I am getting an error.

Comment: No, you would need to create two formula (one for each column) and add them together.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but what if I combine the SUMIF with an index and match formula where I am "targeting" only one column as the sum_range? For e.g. lets say I start the your formula with ```=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet1B2:C13,0,1),...``` I tried this but still getting a #VALUE! error

Comment: to properly answer that would require a new question.  Please post a new question with the new parameters and show what you have tried.  You can link back to this post as reference.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I've created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69572177/sum-specific-column-using-a-lookup-table-values-in-the-lookup-table-are-a-list